# Focus not seen in Qt for Qdial subclass

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt in Visual Studio to get an interface with buttons and knobs etc. I am using this SkinnedDial class - http://dronecolony.com/2012/12/11/customized-qdial-with-qss-support/ , to get a QDial with a custom image. But the problem is that while the other controls are showing the focus frame when I tab over them, this control does not show the focus - for instance button shows the rectangle, but nothing shows up for the dial. Here's the code segment for the dial -

```
SkinnedDial *myDial;
...
myDial = new SkinnedDial(this);
myDial->setRange(-100, 100);
QPixmap *bg = new QPixmap();
bg->load("C:/Current/dial.png");
QPixmap *nl = new QPixmap();
nl->load("C:/Current/needl.png");
myDial->setBackgroundImage(*bg);
myDial->setNeedleImage(*nl);
myDial->setMaxAngle(100);
```

I am new to Qt and C++ and I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: That control does not change its appearance when it receives focus. You'll have to add the code to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok, any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: When you get focus change events, issue an `update()`. Then modify the `paintEvent` handler to draw whatever focus rectangle you want.